# Code to Only Show Content With Specific URL

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode, memberpress

I'm using two shortcode sections in my "Account" page (one Woocommerce for past orders only) and then one shortcode section for MemberPress account details. I want to **only** show the Woocommerce shortcode section when the URL is /my-account/orders/ .

How do I do this? (CSS preferred if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't answer this in CSS but I can with javascript as it is much easier:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

   if(window.location.href.indexOf("/my-account/orders")) {
    $(".codeyouwanttodisplay").show();
  }
  });
```

And if you are hiding the CSS just use:

```
.name {
 display: none;
}
```